# Why I can't see list in template in Django 1.3?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

In view function:
I have

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(id__gt=int(id))
```

And `print str(len(messages))` is 8

In template, I say `{{ messages|length }}` , the result is 0. what happened?

I am sure that I referenced the right template, because I printed some random text on page, and I see that. Why I cant' see the queryset in template? It worked just fine in 1.2.3 I believe, because I've been using this hundreds of times.

Comment: Did you pass it as a context variable?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Check my code  "html = get_template('element/message.html').render(RequestContext(request, locals()))", and I have also tried direct_to_template, both have same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable cause is that your `messages` variable is in fact overridden by a context processor provided by `django.contrib.messages`. Try giving your queryset a different name and see if it helps.

Comment: ....which strikes me as a little odd to begin with. Since messages are tied to a request, why not throw them in request.messages? A context processor which creates (in fact, as in this case, overrides) a variable name strikes me as gnostic and unpythonic.

After all, the sessions framework, upon which the messages framework is build, gives access to the session via the request object - why not do likewise with messages?

Comment: @jMyles Probably not the place for a critique of Django design decisions, I would ask on #django-developers [irc.freenode.net] or the django-developers google group.